# Put string in column table SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

[Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cev9.png)

I am planning to put string in table with my code but its return error. Below is my code.

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!ASA.Value<=60,1,0))&"/"Count(Fields!ASA.Value)
```

can someone help me on this, above is the **image** I found some one did on this.

Comment: should there be another "&"  after the "/"?

Comment: It work on text box expression, but not in the table

Comment: The Sum and Count functions only apply to group totals rather than to each data line.

Comment: Please make sure your are putting this in an appropriate Group footer section. Detail section wont work